# Are there vertices on imported STL files in tree.js?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to import STL files and then reduce the number of vertices using this great mesh simplification function:

http://www.blurspline.com/labs/3D/bunny/

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5806

It seems that geometry.vertices returns "Undefined" after I import via STLLoader. And I think this has to be the reason this does not work for me.

I´m using this code to import it;

```
            var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
            loader.load( 'mySTLfile.stl', function ( geometry ) {

            geometriesParams.push({type: 'Test', args: [ ], scale: 100, meshScale:1 });

            console.log("Vertices:"+geometry.vertices);

            THREE.Test = function() {
                return geometry.clone();
            };

            updateInfo()

            } );
```

Why aren't there any vertices on imported STL files? And does anyone know of a solution to this?

Comment: You can do `console.log(geometry)` and investigate the object, pay attention to the `type` of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`STLLoader`returns `THREE.BufferGeometry`.

In your loader callback, you can convert your geometry to `THREE.Geometry` like so:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( geometry );
```

three.js r.84

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! :)